# Alternative to traffic manager when dealing with internal systems?

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

Basically I want the same behavior of a traffic manager but for internal only systems.

So when my internal system in region 1 goes down, it redirects to the region 2 system.

Comment: Which workloads (on-premises or Azure) do you want to load balance?

Comment: Azure, we're using a lot of resources but none are publicly exposed (like VMSS, ASE) but accessible internally through redundant VPNs.

Comment: You can use the Azure internal load balancer with site-to-site VPN or Vnet-to-Vnet peering

Comment: Hmm so a traffic manager handles failover and priority, etc automatically. I don't see how vnet peering or load balancer would handle this. Would it be manually? Also - this doesn't seem like it would support region failure. I'm thinking I need to handle the swap from on-prem router?